# Tile an image x times to a y px output image in imagemagick

Tags: imagemagick, dragonfly-gem

I am using ImageMagick (via Dragonfly in Ruby) and need to convert an image that looks like this:

`X`

To tile like this:

`XXX
XXX
XXX`

and have a set width (200 px in my case).

How would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With ImageMagick, you would load the source image with the `tile:` format.

```sh
convert -size 200x200 tile:x.png out.png
```

For Dragonfly, you would need to extent the `Dragonfly.app.generate`

```rb
image = Dragonfly.app.generate(:convert, '-size 200x200 tile:x.png', 'png')
```

Comment: How would I handle the DragonFly approach if I am trying to modify an existing image?